# Rating or reviewing an app from the App Store on iOS always silently fails. How to fix?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

Whenever I rate or review an app on from the App Store on iOS, it never saves the rating or review. It only appears to save the rating/review initially, then if I view another app in the store and go back to the previous one, the review isn't saved. If I close the App Store and reopen it, the rating/review disappears.

I can tell that I'm definitely logged in to the App Store as I can see all of my purchases and register new apps to my account.

How do I get the rating/review system to work properly?

Comment: How long are you waiting to check for the review?  It can sometimes take a day or two for ratings/reviews to be seen.  If an app doesn't have enough reviews, Apple won't show anything until the reviews hit a minimum number.

Comment: The reviews are posted on well-established apps that have way more than enough reviews for visibility. The reviews I post never stick no matter how long I wait.

Comment: Are these attempts all from the same device?  Can you try a different device?

Comment: I tested this on my Mac, logged into my Apple account, and can't view my app purchases. How do I view my App Store iOS purchases on a non-iOS device?

Comment: Logged into my Apple account on iTunes and was able to view the icons of my purchases but no way to even click on them to bring up the App Store page and write a review. This is infuriating and falls far below the UI/accessibility standard I would expect from Apple.

Comment: Are these apps all originally downloaded/installed using the same Apple ID you're using to try to write reviews?  I can do reviews on every iOS app I've tried so it's not a system-wide issue that I can see.  Are you able to leave Mac App Store reviews on your Mac apps?

Comment: I only have 1 Apple ID and I use it for all of my Apple purchases. I want to log into the iOS app store from a regular computer (Windows/Mac/Linux), preferably a browser, so I can see if the review process works. There's no clear or obvious way to do that and none of the instructions I found yet work.

Comment: You can't leave reviews via the browser, Apple doesn't allow that.  The only way is to use an iOS device.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/6gykb3/cant_leave_review_on_the_app_store/  and  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3114087  and  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8026835 and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3355418  others are reporting the same problem and nothing in any of those works for me.

Comment: Those are all old discussions and they're trying to write reviews from their iOS device, not their PC.  I recommend contacting Apple if nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a working solution after filing a support ticket.

Click "Write a review" to open the long-form review UI. Don't click on the stars at the top; if any number of them are already highlighted when you open the long-form review UI, click to the left of the first one (just like if you wanted to give the app an invisible 0 stars rating) to clear it.

Write the title and explanation on your review as normal, click Send, and you will be prompted to assign a number of stars. Now you can click the number of stars and save/send the review.